# Changing a program to an object oriented design

Tags: java

I need help rearranging a program I have to use classes constructors methods...so on. It's a game of battleships. I'm not too clear on what classes and constructors and methods I'd need.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleshipLab {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public static void breakln() {
        System.out.println("_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void createBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (String[] board1 : board) {
            for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++) {
                board1[c] = "~";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showBoard(String[][] board) {
        breakln();
        for (String[] board1 : board) {
            if (DEBUG == true) {
                for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + board1[c]);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++) {
                    if (board1[c].equals("S")) {
                        System.out.print(" " + "~");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" " + board1[c]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        breakln();
    }

    public static void createShip(String[][] board, int size) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            int col = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            int row = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                board[row][col + i] = "S";
            }
        } else {
            int col = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
            int row = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                board[row + i][col] = "S";
            }
        }
    }

    public static int userFire(String[][] board, int hits, int torps) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row, col;
        System.out.println("You have: " + torps + " torpedos left!");
        System.out.println("Select a row to fire in: ");
        row = input.nextInt();
        while (row > 8 || row < 1) // Error checking for row
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid row (1 -> 8)");
            row = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Select a column to fire in: ");
        col = input.nextInt();
        while (col > 8 || col < 1) // Error checking for column
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid col (1 -> 8)");
            col = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (board[row - 1][col - 1].equals("S")) {
            hits++;
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~ HIT ~~~~~~~");
            board[row - 1][col - 1] = "!";
        } else {
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~ MISS ~~~~~~~");
            board[row - 1][col - 1] = "M";
        }
        return hits;
    }

    public static void finall(int hits, int torps) {
        if (hits < 4) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but you lost because you didn't sink the ship.");
        }
        if (torps < 1) {
            System.out.println("You have lost all your torpedos");
        } else if (hits >= 4) {
            System.out.println("You have beaten the game battleship, Thanks for playing!");
        }
        System.out.println("Good game, well played!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String[][] board = new String[8][8];
        createBoard(board);
        createShip(board, 4);
        int torps = 15;
        int hits = 0;
        /// Starting real stuff
        while (torps > 0 && hits < 4) {
            showBoard(board);
            hits = userFire(board, hits, torps);
            torps--;
        }
        finall(hits, torps);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of question is too broad and opinion based for SO, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For code review, you should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Noah, you should indeed read those links provided by pvg. I'll give you a bit of advice as answer, but that doesn't change the fact that your question will most likely be put on hold for being too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First a remark:**

1. If you are struggling with your code design, it is often a good idea to take a pen and some paper and draft a rough outline there. For your specific task of turning an existing program into OOP, a [class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) would be a really good starting point.

**Now that that's out of the way**, I'll give you a bit of a notch in the right direction.

In your code, we can find two interesting methods:

- `createBoard`
- `createShip`

Notice how they both start with `create`? This is a very, very strong hint that it would probably a good idea to write classes for those two objects at least:

- `Board`
- `Ship`

When it comes to methods, your current code gives us some pointers again. While I'm not sure about firing torpedos and the like, it looks as if you might want to at least turn `showBoard()` into a method `show` of your `Board` class.

Now, what other classes and methods you need really depends on the rules of that game (I'm not familiar with it), what features you want it to have and, of course, how you want to implement it. Possible other classes could be `Torpedo` but maybe those will just be a primitive type member of your `Ship` class. Another candidate could be something like `Tile`, the basic building block of your `Board`?

You'll have to take it from here, really. The [Java Lessons on Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) will be useful.

Comment: Inside of the board class. I'd use an array of 8 rows and columbs to create the game board. And that would be a method of the class?

Comment: I assume the board will only be generated once and doesn't change size after that? If so, the constructor would be a good place to create the board. If you are feeling fancy and it makes sense for the game, you could hand in the size of the board as argument: `public Board(int size) { /* initialize the board array */ }`

Comment: No, the board size won't change. So I create the board in the constructor and then show the board in a method....

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable indeed. Also, don't actually dismiss the second point I made in the beginning: draw a class diagram (or something similar) on paper. I know it sounds boring, but I promise it will help.

Comment: One more thing, after creating a class how do I use it in the main?

Comment: `Board board = new Board();` and then later `board.show();`.  
By the way, sooner or later you should select one of the answers as accepted answer, unless none of them helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Also, you might want to read through the [Java Lessons on Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/), those seem exactly like what you need right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so when you're doing OOP, before you begin to code you should analyze your problem and break it down. What parts make up the game, what are their functions and attributes, how do these parts interact with each other? I'll help you start, consider making board and cell classes.

In OOP you like Java, you need to create a new instance of the object(class) that you define. So let's say you created a class:

```
  class Shape {
      int length, width;
      String color ="";
  }
```

To use Shape in main you create a new instance of it

```
  class Driver {
        public static void main (String [] args){
               //First you specify the type as your object name, then name the       variable and lastly, you do new object. 
               Shape myShape = new Shape ();
       }
  }
```

Comment: after creating a class how do I use it in the main?